# Apply where condition on same column many times

Tags: php, ajax

I have a catalog page on which products are getting displayed via ajax. The code for Ajax call is below:

function updateProducts(opts){

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "func.php",
  dataType : 'json',
  cache: false,
  data: {filterOpts: opts},
  success: function(records){
    $('#slider').html(makeProdiv(records));

  }
});
```

}

and func.php has code as below:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=filter', 'root', '');

 $select = 'SELECT id, pname, prate, pdesc';
 $from = ' FROM product';
 $where = ' WHERE TRUE';

  $opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');

  if (in_array("Shoes", $opts)) { $where .= " AND ptype = 'Shoes'"; }
  if (in_array("Belt", $opts))  { $where .= " AND ptype = 'Belt'"; }

   $sql = $select . $from . $where;
   $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $statement->execute();
   $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $json = json_encode($results);
   echo($json);
```

The problem i am facing are:

When i select both Belt and Shoes in the filter then no result is getting displayed because the query turns out as below on selecting both options:

```
SELECT id, pname, prate, pdesc FROM product WHERE TRUE AND ptype = 'Shoes' 
AND ptype = 'Belt'
```

Please let me know how to achieve that as single product check is working fine.

Comment: use the IN Keyword if you want multiplr ptypes, like **ptype IN ('Shoes','Belt')** @GagandeepSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed your query will return nothing as soon as you have two conflicting conditions.
To resolve this, you should replace this:

```
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');

if (in_array("Shoes", $opts)) { $where .= " AND ptype = 'Shoes'"; }
if (in_array("Belt", $opts))  { $where .= " AND ptype = 'Belt'"; }
```

By (notice change at end of first line also):

```
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array();
if(count($opts)){
    $where .= " AND ptype IN (". str_pad('',count($opts)*2-1,'?,') .")";
}
```

This produces a WHERE clause like this:

```
AND ptype IN (?,?)
```

Then pass the *$opts* value as argument to *execute*. This is safe for SQL injection, so you don't need to verify the values are in some predefined list:

```
$statement->execute($opts);
```

This way you don't need to adapt your code when you have other types that can be selected.

Answer (score 3):

i figured it out and achieved as below:

```
$allptype = array('Belt','Shoes');
$selectedptype = array();
foreach($allptype as $ptype){
 if(in_array($ptype,$opts)){
    $selectedptype[] = $ptype;
  }
 }
 if(count($selectedptype)){
   $where .= " AND ptype IN ('".implode("', '", $selectedptype)."')";
 }
```

It seems gud to me. If sombody has another approach , feel free to post.